# Match against a variable with pcase

Tags: local-variables, let-binding, pcase

I'm trying to get `pcase` to match against a `let`-bound variable. However, I can't seem to get `pcase` to recognize the variable correctly.

See this minimal example:

```el
(let ((a 1)) (pcase 2 (a 7)))  => 7    ;; as predicted by the docs
(let ((a 2)) (pcase 2 (`a 7))) => nil  ;; ???
```

How can I get `pcase` to return `7` iff `a = 2`?

(An alternative to `pcase` with similar features would also suffice.)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.newartisans.com/2016/01/pattern-matching-with-pcase/) might help?

Comment: @ReneFroger, odd, I assumed that a `(pred ...)` would work (although it would be clumsy, but even `(let ((a 2)) (pcase 2 (\`(pred (lambda (x) (= x a))) 7)))` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How about `(let ((a 2)) (pcase 2 ((pred (equal a)) 7)))`?

Comment: @Constantine ah. I was under the delusion that everything needed to be backquoted after reading the docs. Your example does work. Assuming there's no more elegant way to do it, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: By the way, would something like `(let ((a 2)) (pcase a (1 5) (2 7) (3 11)))` work for you? This would evaluate to 7 when `a` is 2, to 5 when `a` is 1, etc. Is there a reason to use `(pcase constant ...)` instead of `(pcase variable ...)` if you want to match `variable` against `constant`?

Comment: @Constantine no, this is just a minimal example. In actuality, they're both variables. I just used a constant as the casing arg because `pcase` doesn't seem to care.

Comment: `(let ((a 2)) (cl-case a (2 7)))`

Comment: @Drew I really am branching a single variable among multiple other variables, so I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```el
(let ((a 2)) (pcase 2 ((pred (equal a)) 7)))
```

This snippet uses the fact that (rephrasing `(describe-function 'pcase)`) a predicate may have the form`(FUN ARG1 .. ARGN)` in which case it gets called with an `N+1`'th argument which is the value being matched.

Comment: I'm convinced that this is probably the most efficient way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> An alternative to pcase with similar features would also suffice

```cl
(let ((a 2))
  (cond ((eq a 2)
         7)))
;; => 7
```

This isn't a joke - everything that *can be* done with `pcase` can
also be done with a combination of `let` and `cond`.

And it think it *should be* - gratuitous branch-introducing macros
aren't helping anyone to either code faster or maintain
easier. They're introducing *another* language you have to learn, on
top of Elisp.

Comment: Yes, and I do usually use `cond`. Although sometimes `pcase` can be very handy and more clear than a straight `cond` (esp. when it comes to destructuring, which I'm a big fan of.)